# possible collision hashing uuid cakephp

Tags: security, cakephp, hash

Is it possible to have collisions if to use `Security::hash` on uuid() string ? I know that uuid() generates truly unique string, but I need them to be hashed, and I am worried if there is a possibility that the hashed string can be repeated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, contrary to the name, a uuid does not create a truly unique string.  It generates a string that is unique with very high probability(high enough that it can for pretty much all purposes be treated as unique).

As for your chances of getting a collision, that really depends on which hashing algorithm you are using.  Assuming a well built hashing algorithm which distributes uniformly over it's output space, your odds of a collision with any two hashes is `1 / 2^n` where `n` is the hash length in bits.  The odds of any two hashes colliding in a birthday attack scenario can be approximated using the formula `p(h) = h^2 / 2 m` where `h` is the number of hashes you expect to generate and `m` is the output space (2^256 in the case of SHA256 for example).

So, the sum it all up, you will **always** have a chance of getting a hash collision regardless of what hashing algorithm you're using.  However, in the case of pretty much anything equal to or greater than SHA256, the chance is so vanishingly small that is is not worth worrying about.  Your time is better spent worrying about the chances of a bus running over your server in the next second.

Answer (score 0):

uuid can generate duplicates but the chance is very very very small.

Security::hash of cakePHP looks like the hash function of PHP.

If you use it with sha512 it should be pretty good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes in fact, it is a hashing functions from php, like sha1, md5, blowfish. But the sha512 seems a little long string for me, sha1 or md5 won't be enough in ur opinion ? Also, yes the uuid is practically impossible to be repeated, but I was thinking that after hash it could be repeated. Thanks

Comment: md5 and sha1 have known collisions so you should not use them annymore, sha384 should do the job also pretty good.

Comment: Edit  md5 and sha1 have known collisions so you should not use them annymore, sha256 or sha384 should do the job also pretty good but more chance on a collision vs sha512.

Comment: “md5 and sha1 have known collisions so you should not use them annymore” – Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: The internet is full with scientific papers and information about md5 and sha1 collisions.

Comment: And sha256, sha384 and sha512 should also be more less prone to Birthday attack because are better designed